# Modify Treemap-Chart in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, graph, charts, powerpoint

I have a chart that I modify with VBA by changing the values from an excel-workbook. Everything works fine, but I want to use the `treemap-chart` where suddenly the code stops working.

The code works perfectly fine with the other charts in PowerPoint but when I change it to `TreeMap` the Code stops executing and the chart doesn't change it values.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Chart_TT()

 With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("Chart 1").Chart.ChartData
    .Activate
    .Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value = .Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("I9").Value
    .Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("D2").Value = .Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("J9").Value
    .Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("E2").Value = .Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("K9").Value
    .Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("F2").Value = .Workbook.Sheets(2).Range("L9").Value
    .Workbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
 End With

End Sub
```

The error code which is shown is:

> "Error -2147467259 (80004005): The method "workbook" for the object "ChartData" failed.

What do I have to change that the code also works with the TreeMap chart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the treemap chart style is fairly new and has not been included in the VBA object model.